# How to convert a column of timestamps to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a column of dates expressed as timestamps (like `[1554334020000, 1554334200000, 1554334380000, 1554334560000, 1554334740000]`). How do I convert it into datetime?

I know that for a single value you can do

```
datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=int(data['Date'].values[0]))
```

but how do I apply that to the whole column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) passing argument `unit='ms'`

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
```

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [1554334020000, 1554334200000, 1554334380000,
                                 1554334560000, 1554334740000]})
print(df)
```

[out]

```
       timestamp
0  1554334020000
1  1554334200000
2  1554334380000
3  1554334560000
4  1554334740000
```

---

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
print(df)
```

[out]

```
            timestamp
0 2019-04-03 23:27:00
1 2019-04-03 23:30:00
2 2019-04-03 23:33:00
3 2019-04-03 23:36:00
4 2019-04-03 23:39:00
```

Answer (score 4):

If you (already) have a series, all you need is an `astype` call:

```
pd.Series(ts).astype('datetime64[ms]')

0   2019-04-03 23:27:00
1   2019-04-03 23:30:00
2   2019-04-03 23:33:00
3   2019-04-03 23:36:00
4   2019-04-03 23:39:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If this runs you into errors (due to invalid values), use `to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'`.

```
pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='ms', errors='coerce')

DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-03 23:27:00', '2019-04-03 23:30:00',
               '2019-04-03 23:33:00', '2019-04-03 23:36:00',
               '2019-04-03 23:39:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Which returns a `DatetimeIndex`. You can call `to_series` on the result or assign to a column directly.